# HTML - Load images like the web browser normally does

Tags: html, css, file, google-analytics, file-handling

Is it possible to load an image in HTML and load it like an actual image (Like if it was an image/png mimetype etcetera).

Example:

This is me loading an HTML document that contains `<img src="RL_Dark.png">`:

[Loading the image through an HTML document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg0Y1.png)

But here's me loading it directly from the file:

[Loading the image through file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z53yt.png)

Is it even possible to let the browser handle the image loading as I am not planning on doing anything via the HTML document that would be shown to the user (Statistic collection such as Google Analytics and Alexa Analytics), if it is, would anyone be able to show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser (presumably chrome) when given the direct image url, loads the image in a gallery style view (where it applies centering and shows checkerboarding) whereas when given an HTML page, chrome shows a rendered HTML page. Chrome (and other browsers) often have built in UIs for handling different types of files (another instance would be music files)

Comment: And how would I go about forcing that gallery style view? (Possibly mirroring it in PHP via echo on a per-useragent basis?)

Comment: You could echo the base64 data in an img tag